# How to make NPM live server work in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am new to programming.

I have installed Node.js on Windows 7 and then installed NPM live server using VS Code. When I try to start live server it doesn't work properly.

I tried adding the port to the firewall but all goes in vain. I have attached some pictures you can refer to that AND PLEASE HELP!

What I have written in vs code is here. This is what shows in VS Code's terminal:

```
 Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS E:\complete-javascript-course-master\03-Developer-Skills\starter> node -v
v13.14.0
PS E:\complete-javascript-course-master\03-Developer-Skills\starter> npm -v
6.14.4
PS E:\complete-javascript-course-master\03-Developer-Skills\starter> npm install live-server -g
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated opn@6.0.0: The package has been renamed to `open`
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
C:\Users\cc\AppData\Roaming\npm\live-server -> C:\Users\cc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\live-server\live-server.js
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\live-server\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"})

+ live-server@1.2.1
updated 1 package in 21.506s
PS E:\complete-javascript-course-master\03-Developer-Skills\starter> live-server
Serving "E:\complete-javascript-course-master\03-Developer-Skills\starter" at http://127.0.0.1:8080
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
←[90m    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)←[39m
←[90m    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:467:16)←[39m
←[90m    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)←[39m
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
←[90m    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)←[39m
←[90m    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:467:16)←[39m
←[90m    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)←[39m {
  errno: ←[33m-4058←[39m,
  code: ←[32m'ENOENT'←[39m,
  syscall: ←[32m'spawn cmd'←[39m,
  path: ←[32m'cmd'←[39m,
  spawnargs: [ ←[32m'/c'←[39m, ←[32m'start'←[39m, ←[32m'""'←[39m, ←[32m'/b'←[39m, ←[32m'http://127.0.0.1:8080'←[39m ]
}
PS E:\complete-javascript-course-master\03-Developer-Skills\starter>
```

The browser didn't open automatically and when I tried to open it manually, this was the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was not solved, but I installed the Live Server extension and it worked. Try **Live Server** extension.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the execution policy of powershell and the problem is solved.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned-Scope CurrentUser
```